# Having a winforms app wait for a few minutes before proceeding

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I've seen a few references on Stack Overflow about using the `Timer` Class to do what I want but I'm not convinced it's the right solution to the problem.

Basically, I have a button (in .NET 4.0) that when clicked will go through a few different subroutines and do certain things:

- Restart some services
- Launch a command line application that finishes automatically
- Launch a second command line application that finishes automatically
- Launch a third command line application that finishes automatically

The problem I have right now is that the program just goes through each thing and fires it off as quickly as possible - not a problem except that the third command line application **must** only fire after the first three are completed.

I had a `sleep` call in the code, except that this froze the UI and I have a status bar on this application that I wanted to have update to let the user know things are occurring.

I was thinking about a `Timer` object but I'm not sure that would actually cause there to be a pause before doing the next thing.

I'm using a `Process.Start` method to fire off the command line applications, so it doesn't actually raise an event. Should I just have my subroutine raise an event and then have the third `Process.Start` method wait for that event to fire before it goes?

Comment: `Await Task.Delay(x)`

Comment: Should have mentioned I'm trying to stick to .NET framework 4.0. Looks like that is only 4.5.

Comment: Install `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` from NuGet

Comment: If I install a package with NuGet would it be included when I publish the app for standalone use? I've only used NuGet when I'm compiling and running code locally.

Comment: Never call Task.Delay or Thread.Sleep in a GUI app.  The Process class has an Exited event.  You can use it to do the next thing.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2012/12/08/how-to-await-a-system-diagnostics-process.aspx

Comment: @SeanLong: Yes; it will just add DLLs as copy-local references.

Comment: Perhaps you could use the [Process.WaitForExit Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in your thread.

Answer (score 0):

This small snippet might help you. Try to get the idea and implement your own code.

```
     try
     {
        Process myProcess;
        myProcess = Process.Start("Notepad.exe");
        while (true)
        {
           if (!myProcess.HasExited)
           {
               // Discard cached information about the process.
               myProcess.Refresh();
               // Print working set to console.
               Console.WriteLine("Physical Memory Usage: " 
                                    + myProcess.WorkingSet.ToString());
               // Wait 2 seconds.
               Thread.Sleep(2000);
           }
           else {
               break;
           } 
        }

        // Close process by sending a close message to its main window.
        myProcess.CloseMainWindow();
        // Free resources associated with process.
        myProcess.Close();

     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("The following exception was raised: ");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
     }
```